# Invertibility of bordered Hessian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, hessian-matrix

I have an optimization problem: $max_{x \in C} f(x)$ s.t. $Ax=b$, where $x \in  R^n$ and $b \in  R^m$, $m \le n$, adn $C$ compact. I know that $f$ is strictly quasi-concave, and that $A$ has rank $m$ (linearly independent, linear constraints). My question is: can I guarantee that the Hessian matrix bordered with the Jacobian of the constraints is invertible --when all constraints are binding, i.e, the multipliers positive--? That is, can I guarantee that the solution (in $x$ and Lagrange multipliers, which exists and is unique) is differentiable with respect to $b$?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:C\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $C$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f$ is SQC. We consider the extrema of $f$ over $D=C\cap \{x|Ax=b\}$. I assume that you look for a maximum of $f$ over the convex $D$.

What do you mean by "can I guarantee that the solution (in x and Lagrange multipliers) is differentiable?" ?

On the other hand, why do you write that " the solution (in x and Lagrange multipliers, which exists and is unique)" ? The function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is strictly concave and not upper bounded over $\mathbb{R}^+$.

1. The Lagrange method gives the candidates $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ that are solutions of:

$Ax=b$ and there is $\Lambda \in M_{1,m}$ s.t. $Df_x+\Lambda A=0$.

2. You seek THE $x_i$ satisfying, for every $j\not= i$, $f(x_i)>f(x_j)$. If this unique $x_i$ does not exist, then $f$ is not upper bounded or does not reach its upper bound.
3. Otherwise, there are two posibilities: either $f(x_i)$ is the required maximum or $f$ is not upper bounded or does not reach its upper bound.

About your question, consider the case $m=0,n=1$ and the strictly concave function $f(x)=-x^4$. The Hessian in the critical point $x=0$ is $0$.

EDIT. Answer to Rob. You are very kind (rare quality) but you do not understand precisely these issues.

In my post, I assumed that $D$ has a void edge. Since you assume that $D$ is compact, it may have a non-void edge and you are faced with a different kind of problem. Indeed, the max can be reached on the edge in a point that does not satisfy the Lagrange conditions (take $\sqrt{x}$ over $[1,2]$); on the other hand, your claim about the unicity (when a solution exists) is clearly false; consider the function $y=x^3$ over $[-1,1]$ and extend to the right by a bell curve (like a parabola $y=-x^2$); you obtain a SQC function and Lagrange method gives its max and a critical point, in $x=0$, which is not associated to an extremum of it.

Of course, when your compact is defined by a system of inequalities, then you must write Kuhn-Kutter conditions and it is no more the same question...

The last but not the least, you are very unlucky about your last sentence "So, your example $f(x)=−x^4$ is not an issue"; simply see it as a restriction:

$f(x,y)=-x^4+x(y^2-1),[0,1][x,y]^T=[1]$. Then the Hessian in the unique critical (Lagrange) point $(0,1)$ is $\begin{pmatrix}0&2\\2&0\end{pmatrix}$ and is invertible. The bordered Hessian is $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&2\\1&2&0\end{pmatrix}$ and is singular.

PS. I have not checked if my function $f$ above is SQC; otherwise we have to change a little the counter-example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I failed to mention that $C$ (in your notation) is compact as well. Sorry! So, existence and uniqueness of the solutions (and the Lagrange multipliers) is not a problem. What I mean by "can I guarantee that the solution (in x and Lagrange multipliers) is differentiable?"  is differentiable with respect to $b$. In my particular problem, I also know that the Hessian (not bordered) is in fact invertible. So, your example $f(x)=−x^4$ is not an issue. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again, Loup blanc. Apart from your opinions, your example at the end is the only thing that matters. I have formal proofs for the existence and uniqueness of my solution (in $x$ and multipliers). Let us assume that. Do I have an invertible bordered Hessian? Your example says that the answer is negative, but in your example both the multipliers and $x$ are still differentiable with respect to $b$: the derivative of both is $0$. So, are they always differentiable? Is the bordered Hessian invertible if all constraints are binding? Thanks!